# csharp interop excel: how to accessing to pre-formatted styles like "accounting formatting"?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

How to accessing to a pre-formatted styles like "accounting formatting" in c# with Excel Interop ? please

```
table.ListColumns["MONTANTS"].DataBodyRange.NumberFormatLocal = "# ##0,00 €";
table.ListColumns["MONTANTS"].DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = InteropExcel. ENUM ?
```

I'm looking for set table.ListColumns["MONTANTS"].DataBodyRange.NumberFormat to a "accounting format"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I've not tested this.*

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820867.aspx), just use:

```
table.ListColumns["MONTANTS"].DataBodyRange.NumberFormatLocal = "Accounting";
```

> The number format is specified using the same format codes displayed on the Number tab of the Format Cells dialog box. You can use a built-in number format, for example "General".

I suppose you could make a convenience `enum` with all the built-in formats.